# Do the Finnish have a word for getting drunk alone in your underwear?

Tags: language

Urban dictionary (and many other articles on the internet) claim that the Finnish word "[kalsarikännit](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kalsarik%C3%A4nnit)" means:

> to drink by yourself at your house in your underwear with no intention of going out

I couldn't find any Finnish source supporting this and I do not speak Finnish anyway.

Does this word exist in the Finnish language? And if yes, does it mean this?

Comment: There's an English word for it too: _Christmas_.

Comment: @Jeremy: I have never gotten drunk on Christmas *in my underwear*. OK, well, technically I suppose I have - but not **only** in my underwear, which is apparently the point of the question. (Actually, one of my best Christmases as an adult was spent in the O-club annex at the Subic Bay Naval Station staying one drink short of ill for Christmas 1980. But I swear I was in full uniform the entire time :-)).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**Yes, it actually is a Finnish word used by the Finnish people.**

[ThisisFinland](https://finland.fi/) is a site for the promotion of Finland: It is associated with the Finnish Government.

> Produced by the Ministry for Foreign Affairs of Finland and published by the Finland Promotion Board <sub>[This is Finland - About Us](https://finland.fi/about-us/)</sub>

Regarding [kalsarikännit](https://finland.fi/emoji/kalsarikannit/), they claim:

> The feeling when you are going to get drunk home alone in your underwear – with no intention of going out.
>
> A drink. At home. In your underwear. And there is a word for it. Kalsarikännit.

They even have [Finnish emoji's](https://finland.fi/emoji/) to describe the activity:
[image]

Apparently, Google translates it as [**underweardrunk**](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Kalsarik%C3%A4nnit)*[sic]*.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it should be noted that the concept of "word" is fluid and, in highly [agglutinative languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutinative_language) like Finnish, somewhat dubious; Cf. Turkish, which is remarkably similar to Finnish in many ways despite being genetically unrelated, where [*muvaffakiyetsizleştiricileştiriveremeyebileceklerimizdenmişsinizcesine* translates to "as though you are from those whom we may not be able to easily make into a maker of unsuccessful ones"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_Turkish).

Comment: As a Finn giving first hand information about our language *kalsarikännit* is adopted, used and understood by Finnish speakers and it has not been made up just for the sake of having a fun word.

Comment: Every Finn I've spoken to recognises this agglutinative combination, although some have implied it's a word that's in vogue, and reasonably new. @MikkoOhtamaa can you remember when you started using this word?

Comment: @NathanCooper [this page lists](http://www.helsinki.fi/~lkotilai/suomenkielinyt/) it from 2005-2006 and I'd believe it to be at least as old...

Comment: @NathanCooper It seems to have been mentioned at least in a well-known online narrative, later turned a book, called "Juoppohullun päiväkirja", i.e. "Totally Smashed", by Finnish author [Juha Vuorinen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juha_Vuorinen) in 1998.

Comment: hahaha. As a Turk, I read abruptly its English after first word since even I can't well grasp its meaning and had never heard before. @errantlinguist

Comment: @snr: even after reading the English translation I still don't understand what it means. :-)

Comment: @errantlinguist Similarly in Finnish there are grammatically correct but artificial agglutinative constructions which are difficult to parse even to a native speaker, such as the commonly mentioned *epäjärjestelmällistyttämättömyydellänsäkäänköhän*, very roughly translated as the sentence fragment "I wonder if even with his/her ability/tendency to not make things unorganized". I think.

Comment: It's interesting that the emojis are smiling. This, to me, speaks of a sort of desperate, lonely, pathological activity... Surgical spirit from an old bean tin kind of thing!

Answer (score 51):

**It's a real word** (a compound word fromed from *kalsari(t)* (underwear) and *känni* (drunkenness), both rather colloquial versions of these words) and can be found in the [online dictionary](http://www.kielitoimistonsanakirja.fi/netmot.exe?motportal=80) of the [Institute for the Languages of Finland](https://www.kotus.fi/) (the institute in charge of standardization of languages used in Finland). The word is described as:

> **kalsarikänni** ark. humalahakuisesta kotona juomisesta alushoususillaan t. muuten rennosti pukeutuneena. *Otti kalsarikännit.*

Translated to English: "drinking at home in your underwear or otherwise casually dressed, with intent of getting drunk".

The institute is also holding a [Suomen sana -kipailu](https://www.kotus.fi/nyt/teemakoosteet/sanoin_saavutettu_satavuotias_suomi/suomen_sana_-kilpailu) (The Word of Finland - competition). While there isn't yet a winner, [10 finalists were already selected](https://www.kotus.fi/nyt/uutistekstit/kotuksen_uutiset/kotuksen_uutiset_2017/suomen_sana_-kilpailun_finalistit_valittu.25860.news) from a [list of publicly proposed words](https://www.kotus.fi/files/5442/Suomen_sana_-kilpailuun_ehdotetut_sanat.pdf) and *kalsarikännit* is included in the finalists. The selection was done by *"Kotuksen asiantuntijat"* (English: experts of the institute). I'd recon this would exclude any fake words from being in the top 10.

Other compound words found in the top 10 would be *sinivalkoinen* (blue and white, or, through reference to the Finnish flag, adjective for finnish) and *demokratiavaje* (democracy deficit, a term coined by those unhappy with Finland's role in EU decition making).

[image: Crossword puzzle including the words demokratiavaje, elähän, kalsarikännit, löyly, metsä, no niin, perkele, sauna, sinivalkoinen and sisu]